# C# Referencing the return value of a boolean method in another boolean method

Tags: c#

I would like to know how to use the result of a boolean method in another method. The code below contains two methods, one named `ValidateDay` and another called `IsLeapYear`. `IsLeapYear` determines if a user entered integer is a leap year. `ValidateDay` checks if the day a user enters is a valid day based on what number month the user entered. In order the check if Feb 29th is a valid day, I need the `ValidateDay` method to know if the result of `IsLeapYear` is true or false. However, I am not sure how to reference the return value of `IsLeapYear` in the `ValidateDay` method. Any advice would be greatly appretiated.

```
// Determines if day is valid
    public Boolean ValidateDay()
    {
        IsLeapYear();

        if(Month == 1 || Month == 3 || Month == 5 || Month == 7 || Month == 8 || Month == 10 || Month == 12)
        {
            if (Day >= 1 && Day <= 31)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (Month == 4 || Month == 6 || Month == 9 || Month == 11)
        {
            if (Day >= 1 && Day <= 30)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (Month == 2 && IsLeapYear(true))
        {
            if (Day >= 1 && Day <= 29)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (Month == 2 && IsLeapYear(false))
        {
            if (Day >= 1 && Day <= 28)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // Determine if year is a leap year
    public Boolean IsLeapYear()
    {
        if ((Year % 4 == 0 && Year % 100 != 0) || (Year % 400 == 0))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Boolean isLeap = IsLeapYear();` then you can youse isLeap in your if statement `else if (Month == 2 && isLeap)` and `else if (Month == 2 && !isLeap) //! means NOT `

Comment: ofcourse you can call the methode diretcly in your if statements ` else if (Month == 2 && IsLeapYear())` and ` else if (Month == 2 && ! IsLeapYear())`

Comment: one more thing `if (Month == 2 && ! isLeap) ` is equal to `if (Month == 2 && isLeap == false)` and `if (Month == 2 && isLeap) ` is equal to `if (Month == 2 && isLeap == true)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following line you pass the value `true` to the IsLeapYear() method:

```
else if (Month == 2 && IsLeapYear(true))
```

but your IsLeapYear() method takes no parameters and I'm guessing that what you intend to do here is evaluate whether the result of IsLeapYear() is true. Simply change it to the following:

```
else if (Month == 2 && IsLeapYear() == true)
```

or more concisely:

```
else if (Month == 2 && IsLeapYear())
```

to check if the value is false, simply use a ! character before the expression to be evaluated:

```
else if (Month == 2 && !IsLeapYear())
```

or if you prefer:

```
else if (Month == 2 && IsLeapYear() == false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use `IsLeapYear()` and `!IsLeapYear()` to check is or isn't LeapYear.

```
else if (Month == 2 && IsLeapYear())
{
    if (Day >= 1 && Day <= 29)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
else if (Month == 2 && !IsLeapYear())
{
    if (Day >= 1 && Day <= 28)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

There is a [DateTime.IsLeapYear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.isleapyear?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_IsLeapYear_System_Int32_) method in .net library I would use it to check the year is or isn't LeapYear.

```
DateTime.IsLeapYear(year)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do feel like you're over-complicating this a bit.

Try this approach:

```
public Boolean ValidateDay()
{
    try
    {
        return Day >= 1 && Day <= DateTime.DaysInMonth(Year, Month);
    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public Boolean IsLeapYear()
{
    try
    {
        return DateTime.IsLeapYear(Year);
    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```